# Current exciting topics in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

What is new in the world of graph theory in the past few years?  Beyond the basics?

Comment: In my opinion this is not the right kind of question for a Stack Exchange site.  These sites are designed to answer *specific, focused* questions, not "tell me something interesting about topic X" questions.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/openp/)(Douglas West's website) is a good site that lists some open problems. Also, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28440/homology-and-graph-theory) related question about the relationship between graph theory and homology.